# converting a JSON string to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

Hi I need to convert a string to a JSON object so that i can get the value from it
below is my string

> { "USER_NAME": "Desc", "PASSWORD": "hiiiiiii"}

I tried the below code

```
var data='{ "USER_NAME": "Desc", "PASSWORD": "hiiiiiii"}'
var output=JSON.parse(data);
var user=output["USER_NAME"];
console.log(user)
```

But am getting the error as below

```
Unexpected token u
```

I'm stuck here any help will be much helpful

Comment: JSON is a **textual** notation. What you're trying to do is convert a JSON string into a *JavaScript* object.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsbin.com/ejUZaZ/1/edit

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure the error comes from this code?

Comment: The error you've described will not occur with what you have there. My guess is that your actual data has a key that isn't in quotes, e.g. `{user: "foo"}`, which is invalid JSON (`user` must be in quotes -- specifically, double quotes).

Comment: Check if it happens with these values above. Maybe your string contains some JSON non-friendly characters or some JSON syntax error

Comment: Why are you missing semicolons (`;`) at the end of some of the lines?

Answer (score 2):

The error `Unexpected token u` will not occur in what you've posted as your sample data, but it *is* a common error you see when working with JSON, because people frequently create *incorrect* (invalid) JSON that results in that error.

[JSON](http://json.org) is a *subset* of JavaScript object initializer syntax (loosely, "JavaScript object literals"), but being a subset, its rules are different from JavaScript's (more strict).

Your actual JSON string causing trouble probably looks like this:

`{user_name: "Desc", password: "hiiiiiii"}`

...which is invalid because the keys (`user_name` and `password`) must be in double quotes in JSON. This is a common error because they don't have to be in JavaScript; but JSON requires that they do.

So the valid version of that would look more like what you posted in your question:

`{"user_name": "Desc", "password": "hiiiiiii"}`

Comment: the computer generated JSON (using `JSON.parse()`) looks like this: `{"USER_NAME":"Desc","PASSWORD":"hiiiiiii"}`

Comment: @2astalavista: `JSON.parse` doesn't produce strings, it consumes them. I'm not seeing what you're trying to say above.

Comment: JSON.stringify instead

Comment: @2astalavista: I'm still failing to see what you're saying. Yes, `JSON.stringify` produces valid JSON. Whatever the OP is trying to parse *isn't* valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{ "USER_NAME": "Desc", "PASSWORD": "hiiiiiii"}'));
//Object {USER_NAME: "Desc", PASSWORD: "hiiiiiii"}
```

Answer (score -5):

hello please try this i am not sure may be it ll work

```
var str = '{ "USER_NAME": "Desc", "PASSWORD": "hiiiiiii"} }';
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")"));
```